# How does Matlab, Maple, etc…solve algebraic and differential equations internally?

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, maple, mathematica

I would be very interested finding out how does Matlab, Maple, etc…solve algebraic and differential equations internally? Anyone know how they do it?

Comment: I don't see anything in that link about differential equations are solved.

Comment: I haven't checked be Matlab often says the underlying method /algorithm for its functions in the api

Comment: Numerically solve or symbolically solve? I find this question *extremely broad*. This is huge class of problems and methods. Be specific. Ask about a given function or algorithm in these tools. And, in the case of Matlab, make sure that the documentation doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about MAPLE, but MATHEMATICA's algorithms are given in the following (hard to find) link ["Some Notes on Internal Implementation"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html)

(Scroll down to "Algebra and Calculus")

Some of the algorithms (e.g. Gauss Elimination) are textbook stuff, but others are more esoteric, and might be unknown to people outside a specific research community - e.g. Higher-order linear differential equations are "solved using Abramov and Bronstein algorithms."